# Remove Frames from Google Sheet Embeded in Wordpress

Tags: google-sheets, embedding

I have embedded a google sheet into my website but wanted to remove the column headers and row numbers as well the as the bottom bars with "add 1000 rows", etc.  I've already managed to get the height and width right to show just the active cells I want but just struggling to get the right coding to take out these last bits... helps....

[How it currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COeVP.png)

My current code is this:

```html
<center>
  <iframe
    src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QMerfirocmaaNiOljj3gVZZWO77R6gII2_Lm-kiXfPY/edit?usp=sharing?widget=true&amp;rm=minimal&amp;single=true&amp;" 
    width="900" 
    height="2100" 
    data-mce-fragment="1"
  ></iframe>
</center>
```

Can't find the right code to take out the borders.

Comment: The current code is this "<center><iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QMerfirocmaaNiOljj3gVZZWO77R6gII2_Lm-kiXfPY/edit?usp=sharing?widget=true&amp;rm=minimal&amp;single=true&amp;" width="900" height="2100" data-mce-fragment="1"></iframe></center>"

Answer (score 0):

You must read [this](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?hl=en-GB#zippy=%2Chow-published-files-look-when-you-share-them%2Cedit-embedded-spreadsheets) to make it work:

[image]

After you follow the steps, this is the code you need:

[image: embedding a google sheet]

Try out different options as mentioned. For instance:

The code for the entire spreadsheet is:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2LABX-1vWcCoUi3i--scNVJehJKwYwO1TyeE8iNOItKkY5w5LkBfaQi1NX9ziQdkxrMKekRq7H3E3G87/pubhtml?widget=true&amp;headers=false"></iframe>
```

Notice the `pubhtml?widget=true&amp;headers=false` part in the end.
That is where you "play around" and make your changes.

You can try `pubhtml?widget=false&amp;headers=false` or

`pubhtml?widget=true&amp;headers=true` or

`pubhtml?chrome=false&amp;widget=false&amp;headers=true`

Also. Try for a specific tab and not the entire sheet. To do this you must use a `gid`. This is the id that every single tab has and it is in the end or the sheet URL.

Be careful. Not in the above code but in the sheet's URL on the very top. It looks like this: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxx/edit#gid=1234567`. This means your sheet ID is `xxxxxxxx` and the specific tab id is `1234567`.

So if you only want to show the range `A1:R55` from the tab with gid `1234567` your embed code could be:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2LABX-1vWcCoUi3i--scNVJehJKwYwO1TyeE8iNOItKkY5w5LkBfaQi1NX9ziQdkxrMKekRq7H3E3G87/pubhtml?gid=1234567&amp;range=A1:R55&amp;single=true&amp;chrome=false&amp;widget=false&amp;headers=true"></iframe>
```

Comment: THanks, I just don't know what codes to change.  Hence I've given the code as it is currently embedded.  Just need to know what to change/add to remove the frames fully.

Comment: @OliverGuise-Smith You can see I added more information for you. I hope it helps you so you can accept my answer.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.